# Add row under active cell and copy in value from Col B

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am currently trying to write a script on Google apps script for Google Sheets that will insert a row directly underneath the current active cell.  I also want to copy down the contents of only Col B.

Here is what I have thus far:
This snip-bit works great, but there is no "active cell" feature

```
function addrow5() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

 // This inserts a row after the first row position
 sheet.insertRowAfter(5);
```

So, I've researched and found found this:

```
sheet.insertRowAfter(activeCell.getRow());
```

but I'm not exactly how to put it all together.  As far as the copying of Col B, I've yet to chart those waters.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably answered this one already on the google docs Help forum but in case somenone else is interested:

```
function addrow() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
r = sheet.getActiveCell()
    .getRow(),
bVal = sheet.getRange(r, 2).getValue();
sheet.insertRowAfter(r);
sheet.getRange(r + 1, 2).setValue(bVal);
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for and served as a flawless solution my question, JPV was a huge help to me on this!